# vagrant up give me error in laravel

Tags: php, ubuntu, vagrant, homestead

when I run vagrant up in laravel project it gives me this error I an using Ubuntu. 
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The host path of the shared folder is missing: ~/Code
here is screenshot of Homestead.ymal

[image]

Comment: so, you're absolutely sure that the Code folder exists under the home directory of the user under which Vagrant runs, yes?

Comment: My project name is abc and I replaced 'Code' to 'abc' in Homestead.yaml but it gives same error. There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The host path of the shared folder is missing: ~/Code
  even I do not have Code folder

Comment: I'm not familiar with Homestead, but perhaps it has cached your configuration somewhere in that case?

Comment: if it complains about the `~/Code` even when its removed, you can try a vagrant destroy and vagrant up again. beware destroy will completely destroy your vm so if you have stuff to save, save it before you destroy (or make a backup of the vm)